# Inheritance in Laravel

Tags: php, inheritance, laravel-4, eloquent, models

I have two classes. A and B. The class A extends Laravel, the class B extends A.
They rappresent two tables. The table associated with the class B doesn't have a primary key, also a foreign key (A_id). The situation is this:

```
class A extends Eloquent 
{
   protected $table  = 'a';
}

class B extends A
{
   protected $table  = 'b';
   protected $primaryKey = 'a_id';
}
```

I need to specify the primary key in class B cause laravel tries to build the B object with

```
 SELECT * FROM B where id = ?
```

but the field id doesn't exists.

The problem is when i try to access to an A method from B object es

```
$b = B::find(1);
$b->method_in_a_class();
```

the method called execute a query in a C table (also another class), linked with A table, not with B table, so the framework do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM C WHERE B_id = ?
```

but it would be

```
SELECT * FROM C WHERE A_id = ?
```

Why??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

probably the easiest way to solve the problem is to use the one-to-one relationship, so that you have:

```php
class A extends Eloquent 
{
   protected $table  = 'a';

   public function b()
   {
        return $this->hasOne('B');
   }
}

class B extends Eloquent
{
   protected $table  = 'b';

   public function a()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo('A');
   }
}
```

Hope this could solve your problem!

Comment: This is one solution. But not the best one for 2 reasons:
1) logically it's not the same thing
2) i can't access to A methods directly from B instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a primary key in the second table, you should consider merging the tables. Without the primary id, you are not able to use it as a Eloquent model anyway. You have this problems probably because of a bad database design.

Answer (score 0):

First off, to answer your question: Eloquent uses `B` name for foreign key, because you didn't tell it not to.

Imagine this scenario (not entirely like yours, but it's a real one): Post model, Category model, RootCategory model:

```
class Category extends \Eloquent {
  public function posts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
  }
}

// categories are hierarchical, self referencing table
class RootCategory extends Category {
  // global scope and stuff
  protected $table = 'categories';
}

class Post extends \Eloquent {
  public function category()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
  }
}
```

Now, with above setup, calling simple dynamic property will throw - `column not found 'posts.root_category_id'` which is probably what happened in your case.

The reasons for this are:

1. You didn't specify the foreign key to look for...
2. ...so Eloquent calls generic `getForeignKey()` method to guess it

`getForeignKey()` uses `$this`, which is `RootCategory` object, so the foreign key will be `root_category_id`.

---

### So there are 2 ways of solving this issue:

**1 better**

```
// RootCategory model
public function getForeignKey()
{
  return 'category_id';
}
```

2 also working, however requires editing parent class.

```
// Category model
public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Post', 'category_id');
}
```